# Comparing stochastic and deterministic algorithms

Tags: statistical-significance, stochastic-processes

I've been asked by a reviewer to provide statistical results on an algorithm's performance.

My algorithm is stochastic, so 50 runs will give 50 slightly different results and I compare with deterministic algorithms that give the same result each time.

Originally I thought that by simply showing a higher mean and median over 50 runs would be proof enough, but apparently not and I'm unsure which test I should perform.

I don't know if the results follow a normal distribution. And there are four (separate, independent) metrics for each run.

I've been looking at Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test and the single ttest. Would either of these be suitable?

Thanks

Comment: These algorithms stochastic but the proper test depends on whether or not the distribution is normal.  If it is normal the t test is more appropriate because it is a more powerful test.  Otherwise the Wilcoxon rank sum test and not the signed rank test could be better.  The threshold depends on the significance level. The Wilcoxon signed rank test only applies to problems involving two samples.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll look into the Wilcoxen Rank Sum. One extra question that I probably should already know the answer to, do I run this test on each of the four metrics and on each of the datasets tested - for example, DataSet One : metric a ( p value) metric b (p val) metric c( p val).....